# Istio with AWS ECS

Tags: istio

My company is using AWS ECS as container orchestration service. From Istio's documentation I have understood that it works primarily with Kubernetes. Does Istio work with ECS also?

Comment: If you looking to work with kubernetes then EKS is the right service for you.

Comment: Service Meshes enable service-to-service communication in a secure, reliable, and observable way. In this blog post, Matt Turner, CTO at Native Wave, explains the concept of a Service Mesh, shows how Istio can be installed as a Service Mesh on a Kubernetes cluster running on AWS using Amazon EKS, and then explains some key features of Istio and how it helps make your applications more resilient.

Comment: you can follow the guide for more information https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/getting-started-istio-eks/

Answer (score 1):

What i will suggest you to please use Service Discovery for ECS, Where your micro service will be able to connect to each other without hard coding any task ips. Istio is not integrated as of now with ECS. With the help of service discovery, you’ll get a route 53 private hosted zone which can be used to connect with other micro services.